# How to click input element based on text conditions using Selenium and Java

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, webdriverwait

I'm using selenium and junit5 on JAVA. I doing test on turna.com. How to click input button on Pegasus(Text).

Airlinename Types:

- Pegasus
- THY
- Anadolujet

```
<div class="item-domestic departure-flight rt-domestic-item flight" id="1028" style="">   
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <div class="caption">
                <div class="airline-img-wrapper">                   
                </div>
                <div class="airline-tag-wrapper">
                    <div class="airline-name">Pegasus
                    </div>     
                </div>                
            </div> 
        </div>               
        <div class="col-sm-4 text-right amount-wrapper">
            <div class="price">               
            </div>
            <div class="button">
                <input type="button" class="from-in-button" value="Seç" txt="Seçili">
            </div>            
        </div>
</div>
```

My code:

```
WebElement airlinename= findElement(airline_name);
if(airlinename.getText()=="Pegasus")
{
    clickElement(fromBtn); //input button

}
```

I'm trying it :)

```
.airline-name[text="Pegasus"] , .from-in-button
```

Problem: I can not click input button to (pegasus text tag).

Comment: are you looking for java or javascript?

Comment: Are you trying to click on `<input type="button" class="from-in-button" value="Seç" txt="Seçili">` this button with Selenium-Java? Can you share what you have tried so far?

Comment: Yes. Airlinenames; There are thy,anadolujet and pegasus. but i wanna click input button on pegasus text.

Comment: You should show your own code and describe the problem. "I want" is not enough to ask for help on SO

Comment: if(airlinename.getText()=="Pegasus")
        {
            clickElement(fromBtn);

        }

Answer (score 0):

To click on the `<input>` element with respect to the text **Pegasus** you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48989049/selenium-how-selenium-identifies-elements-visible-or-not-is-is-possible-that-i/48990165#48990165) for the `elementToBeClickable()` and you can use the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- `xpath`:

  ```
  new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.xpath("//div[@class='airline-name' and contains(., 'Pegasus')]//following::div//input[@class='from-in-button' and @value='Seç']"))).click();
  ```
- Browser Snapshot (from [website](https://www.turna.com/ucak-bileti/istanbul-sabiha-gokcen-havalimani-izmir-adnan-menderes-havalimani/2020-08-16/2020-08-23)):

[image: pegasus]

Comment: Locate strategies is not run. I trying it. You can see site on https://www.turna.com/ucak-bileti/istanbul-sabiha-gokcen-havalimani-izmir-adnan-menderes-havalimani/2020-08-16/2020-08-23

Comment: i success locator. But it's be very bad locator strategy. //div[@class='airline-name' and contains(., 'Pegasus')]//parent::div//parent::div//parent::div//parent::div//div[@class="col-sm-4 text-right amount-wrapper"]//div[@class="button"]//input[@class="from-in-button"]

Comment: @NurettinŞANSLI Did you try to use the locator from my answer? That worked for me just right. See the updated answer.

Comment: This xpath find anadolujet,thy on after pegasus. I worked by adding to your xpath.